# {"error": "Please use POST request"} - alternative solution to submitting a form

Tags: javascript, forms, jsfiddle, onsubmit

I'm working on a school project and have attempted to create a calculator that can be found at the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ae97vgxz/2/

And my JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Setup variable as empty
var method = "";

// Detect when initial radio button is clicked
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() { 

    // Get the weight from the input box
    var weight = $("#meatWeight").val();

    // If the water method was clicked
    if ($(this).hasClass("water")) {
        var method = weight * 60;
        // Show me what the value is (can be removed)
        alert(method);

    // If the fridge method was clicked
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("fridge")) {
        var method = weight * 793;
        // Show me what the value is (can be removed)
        alert(method);
    }
});
```

When you use it, if you enter a weight first, then select a method of defrosting you will get the correct answer in an alert window.  However, if you press the 'calculate' button you get the following message -

> `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`

From doing some of my own research, I believe this is because I am trying to submit a form and JSFiddle doesn't let you do that.  If I try on a local environment in Chrome, again there is no output.

I am very limited by my JS knowledge (as I'm sure you can see) so I just can't fathom out a solution.  Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong and what the solution might be?

Thanks!

Comment: The `return false;` will not work if there is any runtime error before it. In your JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ae97vgxz/2/, the `defrost` function uses an undefined variable `method`. Then I found *a* `method` which is defined in the scope of `$(document).ready`'s callback function . What's more, the `weight` variable is not used at all. I'm wondering is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake here:

```
function defrost(weight) {
    return (makeTime(method));
}
```

It should be:

```
function defrost(weight) {
    return (makeTime(weight));
}
```

Also, you should change the makeTime function or it won't work. The parseInt clause should be like this:

```
parseInt(time / 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current method of submitting the form is GET

```
<form id="defrostCalculator" name="defrostCalculator" onsubmit="callbackDefrost(this.elements.meatWeight.value); return false;" method="GET">
```

If the destination requires POST, use POST.

```
<form ... method="POST">
```

Comment: It's not about GET or POST. He doesn't want submit a form at all.

Comment: Hi both - in all honesty, I'm stumped and I don't know what I want and what is the best solution.  However, by following both your advice, I believe I am heading in the right direction - and the form now outputs with: 'NaN hrs and NaN mins' - so I guess I'm missing something else - but at least I guess I'm heading in the right direction....thanks very much, both :)

Comment: BTW - here is updated JS fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/09tfow5v/13/ - it now outputs but it always seems to be '2 minutes'...

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of minor issues. However, the major issue you have is that if you want to use a non-AJAX form on jsfiddle, you have to change all your buttons to have the attribute:

```
type="button"
```

instead of what you currently have:

```
type="submit"
```

When you do `<input type="submit"`, jsfiddle.net squawks and fails because you cannot submit form information to their servers. Luckily, you do not need any AJAX or server interaction. So your simple calculator can just use simple buttons.